# Entity Framework 4.1 Code First – validate object model in controller

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

How do I check that the model is correct for an object read from the database.

```
var myModelObject = theDB.myDbContext.myModelObject.Find(1234);
```

Now I would like to control if it is correct according to the rules / attributy in the model... but how?

Answer (score 2):

It is expected that data read from database are correct according to validation rules because that validation rules also defines the mapping. Inconsistency can lead in some cases to exception in object materialization.

If you want to executed validation based on data annotations manually you can use:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
var context = new ValidationContext(myModelObject, null, null);
bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(myModelObject, context, results, true);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more about this Validator, and how it works?

i have tested it like in your example above, and i cant seem to get it to work:

        var u = new Ucenik();
        db.Ucenici.Add(u);
        var valrez = db.GetValidationErrors();
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var context = new ValidationContext(u, null, null);
        bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(u, context, results, true);

Comment: Ucenik class has IsRequired on its atributes, so when i add it to dbContext, and GetValidationErrors than it works fine, i get 3 errors for each of attributes missing.
But Validator does not return any errors. is it configured wrong or?

My Ucenik class comes from code first, but since i am using existing database, i have added validation rules in its *public class UcenikConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Ucenik>* and not in the class definition itself via attributes. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Validator class works only if you use data annotations. It doesn't work with fluent mapping.